# How do I modify the EL opening template in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, el, content-assist

Whenever I am working in a JSP file and I type `${` to start an el (Expression Language) tag, Eclipse will automatically add `}` (with a space before the closing brace) after the cursor so that I get `${ }` instead of `${}`.

Is there a code template in Preferences that I can modify to change this behavior, or is it beyond user preference control?

I have checked in Preferences: Web: JSP Files: Editor: Templates, but none of those templates match. I've also looked in several other sections in Preferences but haven't found anything promising.

Comment: There were no answers for Kepler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106819/get-rid-of-that-silly-space-eclipse-generates-when-you-open-an-el-expression

Comment: @user880772 Thanks for the link, though; there was an answer suggesting turning off auto-close of EL tags, which is an improvement at least.

Comment: http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ

Comment: @Mero that would require me to type `$ { ctrl-space`. Turning off auto-close is a better solution requiring less mental effort. And neither solution fully hits the mark.

Comment: Given there's no straightforward solution (just workarounds and hacks), I have logged a bug on Eclipse's bug tracker in the hopes that Eclipse Mars (the next version after Luna) fixes this.

Answer (score 3):

What @Mero provided (see comments on answer above) might not be an exact answer, but creating a JSP Template probably the closest thing that I've found.

A few notes for anyone that wants to go that route:

Create a new template through menu **Window->Preferences**, then in the drill down menu navigate to **Web->JSP Files->Editor->Templates**. Click **New**.

**Name** is a shortcut you can type (the same way typing `sysout ctrl+space` in Java is a shortcut for `System.out.println()`). I suggest something simple like `el`. This allows you to type `e l ctrl-space` instead of `$ { ctrl-space` to pull it up.

**Context** tells it when it should appear in intellisense. I suggest creating two of this template where one has a context of **JSP Attribute value** and the other has a context of **All JSP**.

**Description** is just informative. Put whatever you want. I put *'EL Script'* myself.

**Pattern** is where you put what will be inserted. Put `$${${cursor}}` or `$${${script}}`, depending on preference. See below for explanation on the differences.

In Eclipse Templates `${}` is how you put variables in the template, so to make it actually print `${}` you have to escape the `$` with a `$$` leading to `$${}`.

The predefined variable `${cursor}` defines where the cursor is after intellisense replaces the `el`, so to have the cursor appear in between the curly braces you want to do this: `$${${cursor}}`.

Using any variable that is not predefined (in this case, `${script}`) will simply put in that variable with a box around it and allow you to type over it and press enter when you're done, allowing you to move to the end of the closing curly brace.

**Note:** I understand that this is not an actual answer, but rather is a workaround. I'm putting it here simply so that those who are fine with a workaround can know how to go about doing it.

**Edit**

For those that don't like having to type `ctrl-space`, a workaround could be to have the template name start with`<` since on JSP pages, the `<` opens the intellisense, so for instance, you could have the name be `<el` or `<$`.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround but not an answer:

Disable auto-close of EL tags. You type `${expression}` and get `${expression}|`, rather than typing `${expression` and getting `${expression| }`. (`|` denotes the cursor location)

See this answer, from when this same question was asked of Eclipse Kepler:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20258401/1021426